# Is it possible to run VB .NET and C# in different pages on a .NET web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to run VB .NET and C# in different pages on a .NET web app?

Picking up a legacy VB .NET project but need to add pages to it, is it possible to write these in C# or can you only have one language per project?

Comment: There are some good converters out there that will port existing code from one language to the other. Is that a possibility? Anyone want to recommend one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply, actually it is possible to run both VB and C# in an ASP.NET project. Please see this post on Tim Heuer's blog. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/02/28/14002.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <codeSubDirectories>
            <add directoryName="VB_Code"/>
            <add directoryName="CS_Code"/>
        </codeSubDirectories>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Create a sub-folder in the App_Code folder for each language you want to support.
For Example:

```
/App_Code/VB_Code
```

/App_Code/CS_Code

Place your VB.NET code in the VB_Code folder and place C# code in the CS_Code folder

Comment: This will only work for old-style web sites (with an App_Code folder), not for fully precompiled applications (where you deploy only the aspx and the code-behind dll).

Answer (score 1):

If this is an ASP.NET project then yes, you can, but only for ASP.NET elements like pages and master pages.  You would only have to change the `Language` attribute on the main directive (like `<%@Page`) to `C#` (or add one if it does not exist).  This works because each page is compiled into a *separate* assembly by the ASP.NET service.

You will not be able to switch languages like this for code-behind files though, since those are all pre-compiled into the same assembly.

However, if I were working on this project with you, I'd be inclined to LART you for doing something like this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one, but it's not trivial, and the hassle required isn't probably worth the gain. After all, pretty much everything you can do in C# can also be done in VB, only the syntax is uglier.

Mixing C# and VB on a per-assembly level, within the same solution, and referencing each other, is really easy though, so if you need to add an entirely new module, you can write it in C# and reference it from the existing VB application.